# Curly braces Php issue in Godaddy all servers

Tags: php, regex

I tried to do this:

```
class new{
$test = "\}";
public function print(){
echo "Test";
}
}
```

Godaddy server will not ignore the curly braces within the " " and will take it in consideration. 
I called them today and they couldn't help at all.

Any idea or a work around this problem ?
I have to use the curly braces inside " ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an odd situation.

Anyway, some ideas that popped into my mind:

- Define it as a constant elsewhere (somewhere it works)
- Read the value from some property file
- Use `url_decode('%7D');`
- Use `chr(125);`

Comment: Update:
The solution didn't work. Still Godaddy code editor doesn't allow any solution but to remove the curly braces or not use these patterns
\} or }}